# HttpNavigationManager has not been initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a simple chat using asp.net 6 with identity and SignalR.

At the moment I'm trying to connect my razorpage chat with the SignalR hub using `HubConnectionBuilder()`. I'm still very much a beginner to Asp.net.

chat.cshtml.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;

namespace LoginServerChat.Pages
{
    public class ChatModel : PageModel
    {
        public const string HUBURL = "/api/ChatSignal";

        private readonly ILogger<ChatModel> _logger;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;
        private HubConnection _hubConnection;

        public List<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
        public string myUser { get; set; }
        public ChatModel(ILogger<ChatModel> logger, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;
            _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(HUBURL)).Build();
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Users = _userManager.Users.ToList()
                .Select(user => new SelectListItem { Text = user.UserName, Value = user.UserName})
                .OrderBy(s => s.Text).ToList();

            myUser = User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

My application stops on line this line `_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(HUBURL)).Build();` with a `HttpNavigationManager has not been initialized` error. I'm not really sure what this error means, how it's used and I didn't find an MSDN entry for HttpNavigationManager.

Some tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem I had was that I was trying to use Razor pages. Razor pages doesn't have NavigationManager since it's running server side. I have to use Blazor which complies to web assembly and runs client side.